# Solving a system of differential equations with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the system of differential equations one gets from a tuned mass damper:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuned_mass_damper.

I first initialize all of the constants, variables, and functions that I'll need.

```
from sympy import *

m1, m2, c1, c2, k1, k2, F0, t, x10, x20 = symbols('m1 m2 c1 c2 k1 k2 F0 t x10 x20')
x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2', cls=Function)

x1_ = x1(t).diff(t)
x1__ = x1_.diff(t)

x2_ = x2(t).diff(t)
x2__ = x2_.diff(t)

eq1 = Eq(m1*x1__ + c1*x1_ + k1*x1(t) - m2*x2__ - c2*x2_ - k2*x2(t) - F0)
eq2 = Eq(m2*x2__ + c2*x2_ + k1*x2(t))

pprint(eq1)
pprint(eq2)
```

which prints:

```
                                                               2              
         d              d                                     d     
-F₀ + c₁⋅──(x₁(t)) - c₂⋅──(x₂(t)) + k₁⋅x₁(t) - k₂⋅x₂(t) + m₁⋅───(x₁(t)) - m₂⋅─
         dt             dt                                     2              
                                                             dt              

  2           
 d            
── (x₂(t)) = 0
  2           
dt            
                               2           
   d                          d            
c₂⋅──(x₂(t)) + k₁⋅x₂(t) + m₂⋅───(x₂(t)) = 0
   dt                          2           
                             dt
```

Then I try passing the two equations to the dsolve sympy function with the appropriate initial conditions:

```
system = [eq1, eq2]

ics = {x1(0): x10, x2(0): x20}

solution = dsolve(system, (x1(t), x2(t)), ics=ics)
pprint(solution)
```

However, I'm met with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyatt_blair/...", line 22, in <module>
    solution = dsolve(system, (x1(t), x2(t)), ics=ics)
  File "/Users/wyatt_blair/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode.py", line 584, in dsolve
    match = classify_sysode(eq, func)
  File "/Users/wyatt_blair/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode.py", line 1458, in classify_sysode
    type_of_equation = check_linear_2eq_order2(eq, funcs, func_coef)
  File "/Users/wyatt_blair/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode.py", line 1568, in check_linear_2eq_order2
    x = func[0].func
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'func'
```

I tried printing the variable `func` in ode.py and found the it was: `[[x1(t), x2(t)]]`.
It seems that ode.py was expecting `func` to look like this: `[x1(t), x2(t)]`. If I change the two problematic lines in ode.py that were failing to:

```
x = func[0][0].func
y = func[0][1].func
```

I get an `ImplementationError`, which is strange because this equation seems like something SymPy could handle as it isn't too crazy.

Am I passing in `x1(t)` and `x2(t)` incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sympy, but just looking at [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html), the first argument to the `dsolve` method should be `an Equality, or an expression`, but you're passing in a list. Is that equivalent? https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/20-ordinary-differential-equations.html has a bunch of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm working based off this: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html, where they say dsolve "Solves any (supported) kind of ordinary differential equation and system of ordinary differential equations." and from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172733/syntax-for-solving-system-of-differential-equations-in-sympy.

Comment: It looks like someone reported the same issue [five years ago](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9251). The developer asked for some additional information but the reporter never came back.